# If $\frac{df}{dx} = 0$ then $f$ doesn't depend on $x$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, partial-derivative

Let $E$ be a convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $f:E \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable. If $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) = 0$ for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ then $f$ doesn't depend on $x$.

I'm having some trouble with this question because that sounds 'trivial', but that isn't true for non-convex sets. Any help?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $f(x,y)$ does depend on $x$.  Then there are real numbers $c_1, c_2, y$ such that $(c_1,y), (c_2,y)$ are in $E$ and $f(c_1,y) \neq f(c_2,y)$.  Let's say that $c_1 < c_2$.

Since $E$ is convex, the set of points $(x,y) : c_1 \leq x \leq c_2$ is contained in $E$.  Define a function $$g: [c_1,c_2] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$ by $g(x) = f(x,y)$.  Then $g$ is differentiable on $(c_1, c_2)$, with $g'(x) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)$ for all $x \in (c_1,c_2)$.  Now $$\frac{g(c_2)-g(c_1)}{c_2-c_1}$$ is not zero, and by the mean value theorem, there is a point $x_0 \in (c_1,c_2)$ such that $g'(x_0) = \frac{g(c_2)-g(c_1)}{c_2-c_1}$.  Now what?

Comment: Wow! That's an absurd because g'(x_0) = (df/dx)(x_0,y) = 0. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Try a proof by contradiction, and use the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem).  Between any $\mathbf a, \mathbf b \in E$, we can consider the restriction of $f$ to the line segment connecting them.  That is, we can consider $g(t) = f((1-t) \mathbf a + t\mathbf b)$ for $t \in [0,1]$.